# Android pattern plotting in Python

Tags: python

I need to make make an android pattern or just a pattern in a 3x3 matrix. The pattern is `[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 0, 1]` and I need to plot it in a 3x3 matrix. The first entry in the pattern is the beginning point and it connects to the second in the row. The result needs to be the following:

```
8, 9, 7
6, 5, 4
3, 2, 1

pattern = [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 0, 1]
matrix = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

lst = ([matrix[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(matrix), 3)])
for i in lst:
    print(i)

for char in pattern:
    matrix[char]=char
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: how can i code it so i get my desired result?

Comment: [so] is not meant to do your homework! Show us a [mcve] to discuss about...

Comment: i dont want stackoverflow to do my homework ofc, i am like 95% done an assignment that hacks an android patern on the base of the HEX value of the gesture key, the only thing i can't figure out is to how to plot the key like the android patern

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
def print_pattern(pattern, cols=3):
    for ii, pp in enumerate(pattern):
        if ii % cols == 0:
            print("")
        print(pp),
```

Then you can call this function as

```
pattern = [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 0, 1]
print_pattern(pattern)
```

This results in the following output:

```
8 7 6 
5 4 3 
2 0 1
```

If you want to print the pattern in the opposite order you can pass a reversed list of your pattern, e.g.:

```
print_pattern(reversed(pattern))
```

Gives the following output:

```
1 0 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 8
```

Comment: close, i think, the pattern should start at bottom right because 8 is the highes number possible

Comment: In your question you mention that the output should be 8 (in the top left) and 1 (in the bottom right). Am I missing something? Or could you update your question showing what the desired output should look like?

Answer (score -1):

This functions accepts an integer `n` and an iterable.  It makes a  list of tuples of width `n` from that iterable

```
def mat(n, it):
    return list(zip(*[iter(it)]*n))
```